# JQuery UI sortable adds an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use JQuery UI's drag/drop with sortable.  When you sort the elements in a "drop zone", it appears to add another (null) element.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable" class="drop">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#sortable").sortable();

$( '.drop' ).droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li').length;
  }
});
```

You can try it out here:  https://jsfiddle.net/udj6p93f/2/

Go ahead and sort the elements and you'll that `length` becomes 6, even though there are only 5 elements.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied this line

```
document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li').length;
```

just after

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

It's 5. And inspected element, drag and drop 1 element. It adds one more list item.

```
<li class="ui-sortable-placeholder ui-sortable-handle" style="visibility: hidden;"></li>
```

[image]

I think that happens because of this.

Fix suggestion:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();

$( '.drop' ).droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li').length - document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li.ui-sortable-placeholder').length;
  }
});
```